# Ratchet Websocket for raspberry pi

Tags: php, security, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I have written a websocket using ratchet. The webserver is nginx and lives on a raspberry pi. The raspberry pi has been connected to the internet with a router through port forwarding. When I access the site at work, all works well. The websocket connects, all the webpages launch. When I try to access the webpage outside of work the webpage works except the websocket. The worst part is I can't even debug it because I need to be outside the local network for the websocket to fail (i.e not at work). At work, I can connect to the server using two IP addresses, the private IP address that is only accessible locally and the public IP address that can be accessed from anywhere. Both IP addresses properly launch the websocket. When I am not at work, I can only access the webserver on the Public IP address and the websocket does not work.

I have been trying to make this work for a day and a half straight now with no success. Does anybody have any suggestions? Even to help me identify the problem?

The websocket code follows the Ratchet Push Server tutorial:

```
    <?php
       require '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';

       $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
       $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

       $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
       $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
       $pull->on('message',array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

       $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
       $webSock->listen(443, '0.0.0.0');
       $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
           new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
               new Ratchet\Websocket\WsServer(
                   new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                       $pusher
                   )
               )
           ),
           $webSock
       );
       $loop->run();
    ?>
```

The client side code is:

```
    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://privateIPAddress:443',
        function (){
            console.log("Here");
            conn.subscribe('client',function(topic,data) {
                console.log("hey");
                ...
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('Websocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
```

I suspect the issue is a security setting since both the public and private IP addresses work when I am at the work site.

Comment: This `var conn = new ab.Session('ws://privateIPAddress:443',` needs to be your `publicIPAddress`

Comment: If I replace that line with my public IP Address, the browser fails to connect to the webserver whether or not I am on the local network or public network @cmorrissey

Comment: That seemed like a reasonable solution, but then something else breaks.

Comment: You're right that's part of the problem. But Now how to make the websocket work with a public IP address?

Comment: maybe try changing `$webSock->listen(443, '0.0.0.0');` to just `$webSock->listen(443);`

Comment: When I use the public IP address, the error I get is client side. I was using autobahn to connect to the websocket from the client side. The error that is thrown is in this import, so I will try to setup the websocket without this package and hopefully I get a more useful error message

Comment: If I attempt to establish a websocket connection with WebSocket("ws://publicIPAddress:443") the error that is returned is `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` the google returns (Opcode -1)?

Comment: The problem is if the system is set up with port forwarding, trying to open a websocket at publicIPAddress:443 is gibberish. That port of the public IP address is not pointing to anything, even if I have the websocket running on port 443 on the pi. All commands that reach the pi go through port 80 of the router, I just need to send any commands with websocket in their header to the correct port after the fact. So I need to figure out how to make a reverse proxy? In nginx?

Comment: I forwarded the websocket on port 443 of the local machine through port 443 of the public address. Now, accessing publicIPAddress:443 accesses privateIPAddress:443 so it works. But it would be nice to do everything on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very late answer to my own question but in case anyone is still puzzling over the same issues. The answer is don’t use ratchet. Use nodejs with socket.io. All your troubles will fly away. Socket.io which also has a java implementation is simply a more developed package for WebSockets.